# Weird VPN Connection Issues

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox, vpn, browser

I am currently using the latest version of Windows 10. I have been using Tunnel Bear to encrypt my data while browsing the web for some time now. Recently however, when I turn tunnel bear on, no matter what server I connect to, my Chrome browser was unable to connect to any website, spitting out a DNS resolution error at me. I then thought that my ISP (Comcast) was suddenly blocking my VPN or at least throttling it. before conceding and coming to that conclusion however I switched to my Tor browser. I was able to browse the web just fine with that browser. So I went back to Chrome and tried clearing my cache and disabling all add-ons. That didn't seem to work. So I downloaded a few other browsers to see if I could connect with any of those. First I tried Firefox, no such luck, then I tried Opera, nope. I then decided to try Edge and strangely enough, I can connect with edge just fine. I even ran a speed test and am getting the same download speeds as I do when not connected to VPN at all. I don't really want to use edge however though, ide rather use Firefox. Is there any ideas anyone has about this issue?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your mixing oranges with apples.  TOR is a proxy, Tunnel Bear is a VPN, how a proxy works and how a VPN are not the same.  Have you tried to, use the VPN, but configure your DNS, to something other then the VPN's DNs?

Comment: I understand the distinction between TOR and a VPN. I was merely saying that when I used the TOR browser whilst in VPN that browsing worked. I haven't tried changing my DNS routing. I will try that and then update with my findings.

Comment: Proxy would have used your ISP's DNS whereas The vpn unless configured otherwise would use the vpns dns.  Your problem seems to be a dns problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. Sorry for the super later response. Turns out that Tunnel Bear has a plugin on the chrome store which fixed the issue.